# Why pod is the smallest unit?

Tags: kubernetes

In almost every article, it is mentioned that pod is the smallest unit of Kubernetes?

What does it mean? What is the meaning of smallest?

Answer (score 4):

Smallest unit in that context means "smallest deployable thing".

Technically a container is an even smaller unit because a pod can contain multiple containers, but you can not deploy a single container, only a pod with one container. That's why the pod is considered the smallest unit in kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

A word may be the smallest unit in a book. A sentence is made from words. A paragraph is made from sentences. And a chapter is made from paragraphs.

Likewise, in Kubernetes a pod is the smallest unit that exists, and other abstractions build on top of it. For example, a replica set is using the pod. And a deployment is using the replica set.

It may also help to read this [comic](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/kubernetes-comic/), it's one thing that is a bit explained there.

> Pods are the smallest building block in the kubernetes object model. The pod *sees* the container but kubernetes only *sees* the pod.